How to properly calcualte Realized Variance for WTI?
I have several realized variances for WTI, RV, scaledRV, RSVN(negative) and RSVP(positive), which were given to me by a professor whom I cant contact anymore. When I try to calculate my own RV (in eviews)first getting the log difference returns(@dlog(wti)) then multiplying that by 100 getting the cumulative sum and then taking the absolutes of cumsum
series wtiRV = @abs(@cumsum(@dlog(wti)*100))

Does anyone have a clue as to why this 2 graphs are different?
I get this graph:

which is the closest to what the professor made:

EDIT: @newquant mentioned using  ∑|r| or squared log returns but they both dont make a graph similar to the professor's.
series wtiRV =@cumsum(@dlog(wti)^2)
series wtiRV =@cumsum(@abs(@dlog(wti)))

10day @mav

30day @mav

series wtiRV =@dlog(wti)^2

daily RV (even if multiplied by 100, as people usually do ,doesnt do it)


It could be possible that the lookback period is different. I see that the realized variance is usually lower in the Prof's graph compared to yours. If you compute RV over a longer period and more returns, what happens is that the var itself is less responsive to the recent fluctuations and more "stabilized".

@KaiSqDist What exactly do you mean by lookback period? should I add a moving average in my log returns?

That calculation doesn't seem correct to calculate realised variance.
Summing the log returns isn't going to give you a variance, it'll be something like an expected return, which you are then taking the absolute of afterwards.
You need to sum the squared log returns to give you a variance figure or, if you can't do that, then you should be taking the sum of the absolute log returns, not the absolute of the sum of returns.
$$ \sum|r| \neq \left|\sum r\right| $$
Do this and you'll notice that your new graph will have a 'floor' near 0 but above it - just like your professor's graph, whereas your current graph goes to 0, this is where price hasn't moved over your rolling period.

Please check OP I added the 2 graphs that you suggested. They are obviously different from the professor's. I also dont understand some of your sentences ,can you check them.

Your professor is likely doing a rolling period average variance. So the 2nd "WTIRV" chart is closer to this. Are you just plotting single day squared moves? Try taking a 30 day sum or average to return a chart like your professors.
Which sentences do you not understand?

will try, I meant your last paragraph. Did you mean it will "not" have a floor? And the "price moved over" was slightly clarified by your comment now, you suggest making an MA for my daily RV? Or calculate the 30-day window RV? Yes its just daily RVs

Doesnt work, I tried taking the MA of existing daily RV, taking the RV of 30day MA WTI prices and the squared difference of 10-dayMA log returns minus daily log returns and they all produce a broken up line without the floor at the "20" level.

None of those are typical ways to calculate RV. Just take a 30 day average of the squared returns.

Please check OP for the MAs, the graph becomes somewhat similar but there is no floor near 20 and the biggest spikes have different heights. What else could I use?Will it help if I send some of the data?

I found one thing that incorrect even though his charts says rvariance,rsvn,rsvp scaled RV he doesnt "log" them until after some place in the code. I now have to find what he does before "log" because simple returns is not the same chart.

send me your time series data please.

https://files.catbox.moe/5ozz7d.wf1 (eviews 13)

https://files.catbox.moe/pb5rz7.csv (csv if you dont have eviews)

It could be that he is sampling intraday wti prices and making the squared daily returns chart before "loging" it later in the code. I think it should be possible to create near identical graph daily prices. P.S. A reminder: the values of the RVariances are not log'd in the files I have and sent.

I accepted the answer, but there still is the issue here discussed.

I think I found  what that chart is, OVXCLS. I dont understand why it was named "rvariance"

Correction: I think the chart is some kind of manipulation of the OVXCLS. I dont understand why it was named "rvariance"
